# testing js variable declaration speed

Tags: javascript, performance

I want to do some speed tests on very basic stuff like variable declaration.

Now i have a function that executes X times to have a more significant time difference.

http://jsfiddle.net/eTbsv/ (you need to open your console & it takes a few seconds to execute)

this is the code:

```
var doit = 10000000,
    i = 0,
    i2 = 0;

//testing var with comma
console.time('timer');      
function test(){
    var a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z;
};
while (i<=doit){
   test();      
   i++;
};
console.timeEnd('timer');

//testing individual var declarations 
console.time('timer2');
function test2(){
     var a; var b; var c; var d; var e; var f; var g; var h; var i; var j; var k; var l; var m; var n; var o; var p; var q; var r; var s; var t; var u; var v; var w; var x; var y; var z;
 };
 while (i2<=doit){
     test();
     i2++;
 };
 console.timeEnd('timer2');
```

Now i have two questions:

1. Is this an accurate way of testing the speed of variable declarations?
2. how could i test more cycles without having firefox to crash? If i set `doit` to 1000000000 for example, firefox want to stop the script.
3. why are my results (of my script and in jspref) so different each time? Sometime the individual variable declaration is faster then the grouped :/

*edit* just made JS Pref testcase: http://jsperf.com/testing-js-variable-declaration-speed would be nice if some of you with different browsers and configuration could participate. But im still interested to know if this way of testing it is accurate.

Comment: Have you come across http://jsperf.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this an accurate way of testing the speed of variable declarations?

It's good enough to get a rough idea, but it's not perfect.  Like most things, it relies on the CPU.  If the CPU spikes during testing due to another application, such as a virus scanner, or another action from the browser, such as a phishing check, the JavaScript execution can be slowed.  Even when the CPU is idle, it's not an exact science and you will have to run it many times to get a good average.

> how could i test more cycles without having firefox to crash? If i set doit to 1000000000 for example, firefox want to stop the script.

Firefox limits JavaScript execution to a maximum of 10 seconds.  I'm not sure if there's a work around.

> why are my results (of my script and in jspref) so different each time? Sometime the individual variable declaration is faster then the grouped :/

Because there's probably no real difference between the two. All variable declarations are "hoisted", and it's likely that this is done at parse-time instead of run-time as an optimization, so the internal representation of the functions after they have been parsed would be identical. The only difference is the subtle factors affecting the time it takes to initialize the undefined variables and execute the otherwise empty functions.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to 2 Interrupting your loop for user input is the only way I can think of to easily stop the unresponsive script dialogs.

So display an alert every n iterations (obviously stop your timer for this duration).

Have you considered doing this in spidermonkey etc or are you specifically interested in the browser implementations?

Comment: i just try to proove to my wokring buddys that its not only more beautyfull to make grouped variable declaration but also faster.